# 'NSInvalidArgumentException' error when adding data to a UITable?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

So this is the set up of my app. In my view did load method, I create an NSMutableArray, and I initialize it with a list of object (using the `initWithObjects:` method). This array get's loaded into a table view without any problems. I've also added a "+" button in the navigation bar to add data to my table.  My problem is that every time I press this "+" my app freezes and I get the SIGABRT signal. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I've retained the array using a property, and I've synthesized it. I'm also releasing it in the dealloc method.

I'm creating the array like this:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"data 1", @"data 2", @"data 3", nil];
self.myArray = array;
[array release];
```

I'm creating the "+" button in the nav bar with this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *addDataButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"+" 
                                                                     style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                                                                    target:self 
                                                                    action:@selector(addData)];
```

My method for adding data is:

```
- (void)addData {

    [myArray addObject:@"some data"];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

Also if this helps at all, the error message I get in the console is this:

```
2011-02-19 13:02:09.987 MyApp[480:307] -[__NSArrayI addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1bee50
2011-02-19 13:02:10.020 MyApp[480:307] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1bee50'
```

Comment: could you post code where you create myArray - it looks like it is not NSMutableArray, but NSArray for some reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating an `NSArray` and not an `NSMutableArray` and so you can't add objects to it. Change the array initialization to:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"data 1", @"data 2", @"data 3", nil];
```

Comment: perfect that was exactly my problem. I can't believe I missed that. Thank you.